# Explode a string into a hashmap for searching?

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this being returned from my backend:

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6"
```

I have a large array locally and want to display only those items not in this list, so I was thinking of exploding this string into an array but how can I search efficiently? As far as I know there are no hashmaps in JS so how does one do this? I just need to check for key existence.

Comment: You want to display items from the newly returned list that aren't in the local array, or vice versa? Is the list from the backend always going to be small?

Comment: @SimonJ: Yes that's correct. The list initially starts up small but could grow larger but will not exceed the size of the large local array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Javascript objects are also hash tables that can store string or numeric keys:

```
var x = {};
x["foo"] = 1;
if("foo" in x) { alert("hello!"); }
if("bar" in x) { alert("should never see this"); }
```

Comment: True, but does not answer the real question (check for a number existence in the given string)

Comment: Thanks. I will adapt this for my need.

Answer (score 2):

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6".split(",").some(function(letter) { 
  return letter === '2' 
});
```

Warning: Might not work in IE (or other crappy browser)

**Cross browser version (that relies on native code for performance):**

```
var arr = "1,2,3,4,5,6".split(",");
if(arr.some)
{
  arr.some(function(letter) { 
    return letter === '2' 
  });
}
else
{
  for(var i  = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++ )
  {
      if(arr[i] === '2') return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks but I was looking for a cross-browser solution... Need to support crappy ones as well unfortunately :)

Comment: There you go! fast and improved crappy-browser ready solution :)